# Regression table with asterisks, parentheses and different number formats

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I'd like to format a regression table that has asterisks, parentheses and different number formats. In particular, coefficients have three digits, but I have one row with the number of observations, which should not align. I want it to be centered. 
Here's a MWE (btw, I also noticed a clash between breqn and dcolumn. Is there an alternative because I'd like to use both of them?):

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D..{#1}} % for alignment of numbers on decimal marker
\begin{document}
\begin{table}       

\begin{tabular}{@{} l d{4.6} d{4.6} @{}}                                        
    &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)} &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}     \\
$\Delta \ln E_k$    &   0.594^{***} &   -0.934^{***}\\
    &   (0.092) &   (0.051)     \\ [.05cm]
N   &   219,434 &   219,434 \\ [.05cm]
$R^2$   &   0.142   &   0.034   \\
\end{tabular}                                           

\end{table}     
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Christian welcomes @Christian… :o)

Comment: @Bernard: I will write same thing if you welcome another Bernard then :-P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `\multicolumn` with 1 column to override the format for the `N` entries.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D..{#1}} % for alignment of numbers on decimal marker
\begin{document}
\begin{table}       

\begin{tabular}{@{} l d{4.6} d{4.6} @{}}                                        
    &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)} &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}     \\
    $\Delta \ln E_k$    &   0.594^{***} &   -0.934^{***}\\
    &   (0.092) &   (0.051)     \\ [.05cm]
    N   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{219,434} &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{219,434} \\ [.05cm]
    $R^2$   &   0.142   &   0.034   \\
\end{tabular}                                           

\end{table}     
\end{document}
```

yields:

[image]

**Edit:**

As for your other question, `dcolumn` and `breqn` don't seem to play well with each other. An alternative to `dcolumn` is the excellent `siunitx`. Takes some additional work, but it provides more control. The following yields the same result and shouldn't clash with `breqn`. The non-number components in the columns are protected by braces and the `table-space-text-pre={$^{***}$}` and `table-space-text-post={$^{***}$}` in the `S` column type declarations ensure that the *number* is centered in the column and that there is sufficient room for non-number components.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}       

\begin{tabular}{@{} l S[table-format=1.3,table-space-text-post={$^{***}$},table-space-text-pre={$^{***}$}] S[table-format=1.3,table-space-text-post={$^{***}$},table-space-text-pre={$^{***}$}] @{}}                                        
    &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)} &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}     \\
    $\Delta \ln E_k$    &   0.594{$^{***}$} &   -0.934{$^{***}$}\\
    &   {(}0.092{)} &   {(}0.051{)}     \\ [.05cm]
    N   &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{219,434} &   \multicolumn{1}{c}{219,434} \\ [.05cm]
    $R^2$   &   0.142   &   0.034   \\
\end{tabular}                                           

\end{table}     
\end{document}
```