# How to combine breqn and dcolumn package?

Tags: breqn, dcolumn

is there a way to use both breqn and dcolumn packages? 
I constantly get an error message ('Missing } inserted').
Or is there any other package that breaks up equations and sets the equation number in the center of the two lines? 
Thanks!

Comment: You could try `siunitx` in place of `dcolumn`.

Comment: A [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) is needed.

Comment: To clarify, you would have to use the `S` column instead of the `D` column type, in addition to substituting `\usepackage{siunitx}` for `\usepackage{dcolumn}`. [An example](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/272652/89497)

Comment: Thanks, Guho. I saw your answer to my previous question after asking this one....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the use of `.` as the typeset separator, other separators like `\cdot` work OK, if you need a `.` the easiest is to hide it in an `\mbox`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\setlength\textwidth{6cm}
\begin{document}

\begin{dmath}
1+2+3+4=5=a+b+c
=z
\end{dmath}


\begin{tabular}{lD.{\cdot}{3.2}}
aaa&123.4\\
a&1.23\\
aa&11.22
\end{tabular}


\begin{tabular}{lD.{\mbox{.}}{3.2}}
aaa&123.4\\
a&1.23\\
aa&11.22
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Would you anticipate any issues with using that approach in general (i.e., *always* placing the new separator into an `\mbox`)? Obviously you would need to switch back to math mode therein if need be (i.e., for your `\cdot` example it would be `D.{\mbox{$\cdot$}}{3.2}`).

Comment: @Guho no if you switch back to math at that point you defeat the trick, I just used mbox to get a text . as breqn has stolen the math . and putting it back is harder and in most setups it is exactly the same character anyway.

Comment: Nice. That's a fairly easy workaround. Thanks.